# How to clone a repository on a website other than github?

Tags: git, url, github, repository, vlc

I am trying to clone the vlc library from this link http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=generated/3.0;hb=HEAD, but I dont know what url I need to pass to git clone.

Comment: URLs with a question mark `?` in them are passing parameters to the server. If you simply snip off the `?` and parameters to get http://git.videolan.org/ you'll get instructions on cloning.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this link for clone this repository

```
https://git.videolan.org/git/vlc/bindings/python.git
```

After clone change current branch to proper branch which you want

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to find the URL of the repository which is most of the time displayed on the main page of the repository.

Here you should click on 'summary' and it is displayed...

Answer (score 0):

If Maxims answer wasn't clear enough `git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/vlc/bindings/python.git` Does the job.